# How do I remove a column from a table in beautifulsoup (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table

I have an html table, and I would like to remove a column.  What is the easiest way to do this with BeautifulSoup or any other python library?

Answer (score 2):

[lxml.html](http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html) is nicer for manipulating HTML, IMO. Here's some code that will remove the second column of an HTML table.

```
from lxml import html

text = """
<table>
<tr><th>head 1</th><th>head 2</th><th>head 3</th></tr>
<tr><td>item 1</td><td>item 2</td><td>item 3</td></tr>
</table>
"""

table = html.fragment_fromstring(text)

# remove middle column
for row in table.iterchildren():
    row.remove(row.getchildren()[1])

print html.tostring(table, pretty_print=True)
```

Result:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>head 1</th>
<th>head 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>item 1</td>
<td>item 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortuantely, the version of lxml I had didn't support fragment_fromstring, and the codespeak servers were down, so I couldn't update.  I ended up just using beautifulsoup because it turned out every cell in that column had a special class on it, so it was easy to delete via the class name.